# detectTapGestures returns constant offset when TalkBack (screen reader) is enabled using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

`detectTapGestures` returns the expected onTap / onPress asset when TalkBack is disabled, however, when TalkBack is enabled, the offset being returned is a constant in the center of the view.

Jetpack Compose Version: **1.2.0-beta01**

Example:

```
Text(
   modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
           detectTapGestures(
                    onPress = { offset ->
                        Log.d("", "onPress $offset")
                    },
                    onTap = { offset ->
                        Log.d("", "onTap $offset")
                    }
                )
            },
            text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore"
        )
```

When Talk back is turned off, the output is as expected:

```
onPress Offset(151.0, 29.0)
onTap Offset(157.0, 18.0)
onPress Offset(699.0, 62.0)
onPress Offset(391.0, 17.0)
onTap Offset(361.0, -1.0)
onPress Offset(282.0, 85.0)
onPress Offset(729.0, 48.0)
onTap Offset(770.0, 40.0)
```

When Talk back is turned on, a constant offset is received:

```
onTap Offset(540.0, 46.0)
onPress Offset(540.0, 46.0)
onTap Offset(540.0, 46.0)
onPress Offset(540.0, 46.0)
onTap Offset(540.0, 46.0)
onPress Offset(540.0, 46.0)
onTap Offset(540.0, 46.0)
onPress Offset(540.0, 46.0)
```

It is returning the center offset of the view when TalkBack is enabled. After stepping through the code for `detectTapGestures` in `TapGestureDetector.kt`, it appears `awaitPointerEvent()` in `waitForUpOrCancellation` returns a constant position if TalkBack is enabled.

Is there a way around this issue or is this a google bug? Any help is greatly appreciated!